# Nested Transaction DbContext SaveChanges Throws Exception

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-4.1

Suppose I have two nested transactions and both have transactionScope RequiresNew and now suppose the outer transaction saves the entity but the transaction is not committed yet and now the inner transaction make some updation on the entity saved above and saves it to db but on Committing transaction it throws exception. Yes it is logically true since the changes made by outer transaction are not Committed but I would like to know exactly why is it so? I am using EF 4.1 DbContext and TransactionScope.Any help will be highly appericiable.

Comment: Are you getting a deadlock exception by any chance?

Answer (score -2):

while nesting transactions my be technically possible, they don't make any sense logically/conceptually. i would simply avoid nested transactions.

Comment: actually the nested inner transaction is of another service and do some logical work and then save

Comment: maybe so but that can be structured so that nested transactions are not required.